# Join SQL the book_list with recursive my book_category with PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recursion

I have two tables names `book_list` and `book_category`. Schema is like below:

**book_list**

```
+---------+--------+-----------+  
| id_book | id_cat | book_name |     
+---------+--------+-----------+     
|   1     |    3   | Book Nam1 |
|   2     |    1   | Book Nam2 |
|   3     |    2   | Book Nam3 |
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

**book_category**

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+
| id_cat | cat_name | id_parent | level |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+
|   1    |   name1  |     0     |   1   | 
|   2    |  name1.1 |     1     |   2   |
|   3    |name1.1.1 |     2     |   3   |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+
```

code tried:

```
SELECT a.id_book, a.id_cat, a.book_name, b.cat_name, b.level 
FROM book_list a
INNER JOIN book_category b  ON  a.id_cat = b.id_cat
```

I need to manipulate the result array to add breadcrumb where each has link to itselfs like:

```
table row:
<td>3(id_book)</td>
<td>Book Nam3 (book_name)</td>
<td>
  <a href="handle.php?id=<?=id_cat;?>">Name 1</a> » 
  <a href="handle.php?id=<?=id_cat;?>">Name 1.1</a> »
  <a href="handle.php?id=<?=id_cat;?>">Name 1.1.1</a>
</td>
```

Hope I made my point and thank you for any help.

Comment: check your quesry you are selecting a.id_book two times and a.level which doesnot exists, correct it first.

Comment: @Jason_vorhess, you're right. SQL is corrected, thanks for tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query.

```
SELECT
  bl.id_book, bl.id_cat, bl.book_name, tc2.cat_name, tc2.level
FROM
  book_list bl
JOIN book_category tc
  ON tc.id_cat = bl.id_cat
JOIN book_category tc2
  ON LOCATE(tc2.cat_name, tc.cat_name) > 0
WHERE
  tc.id_cat = 3
```

This query is based on occurrence of `cat_name` substrings.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
SELECT a.id_book, a.id_cat, a.book_name , b.cat_name, b.level 
FROM book_list a
JOIN book_category b  ON  USING(id_cat)
```

and then

```
<a href="handle.php?id=<?=$id_cat;?>"><?=$cat_name?></a>
```